# ssrs dynamic table creation

Tags: sql, dynamic, reporting-services

I am passing a tableName from one report to another drill through report in SSRS. My drill through report should create a table dynamically based on dynamic dataset.

Is this possible or I am trying to achieve impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything in Reporting Services is an expression, including the Sql query statement. You can pass the table name as a parameter and then use this to dynamically build a query.

Right-click the dataset, click `Dataset Properties` and click the expression editor beside the query box, which is the `fx` button. Now we can edit the query as a string expression.

Let's say you wanted your report to print a Code and Description from various lookup tables with the specific table name passed as a parameter when you drill down. Edit the dataset's Sql expression to look like the below:

```
="SELECT Code, Description "
&" FROM " & Parameters!TableName.Value
&" ORDER BY Code "
```

When the Sql statement is based on an expression, the `Fields` collection is not updated automatically so you have to add the fields manually. In the `Dataset Properties` edit the `Fields` collection and add the fields that are in the dataset. Note that, even though you are using different tables, the fields in the dataset need to be consistent so you can link them to your table cells.

If the fields from your table have different names then you need to alias them to the names you have added to your `Fields` collection in your Sql. Lets say `ThisTable` has fields `Id` and `Name` and `ThatTable` has `Code` and `Description`.

```
="SELECT " & IIF(Parameters!TableName.Value = "ThisTable", "Id", "Code") & " AS Code, "
& IIF(Parameters!TableName.Value = "ThisTable", "Name", "Description") & " AS Description "
&" FROM " & Parameters!TableName.Value
&" ORDER BY Code "
```

So we have aliased all fields to be returned as simply `Code` and `Description`.

Of course, this will get messy if you have a lot of different field names and a lot of different tables. In that case you may be better off creating views to do the aliasing for you and using the views in your dataset or using a stored procedure.

Comment: but when I create a table on SSRS report, it doesn't show up the fields in dataset, because dataset it build up on dynamic "Databse table name", it doesn't show any fields. How can I create table/matrix with help of this dynamic dataset.

Comment: Yes, you have to add the fields manually. I'll update answer to include this.

Comment: Please help me with this, dataset is not populating any fields. so the SSRS report can't have any fields on it.

Comment: When the dataset is based on an expression it won't automatically populate the field list, you have to do it manually. See the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Thank you that worked very well, is there any option when the column names in two tables are different.

Comment: Yes, you have to alias the field names to a common name that you use in your report. Answer updated. This may make the Sql expression a bit unwieldy so you have to consider whether this is the right solution if you are doing a lot of manipulation like that.